# Inserting timestamp into Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to insert some timestamps into an Oracle DB table but getting an `ORA-01843: not a valid month` error. The format of the string is how the data is pulled so if there's any issue with that, I'll have to correct that after the data is pulled.

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME
(START_TIME,
 END_TIME
)
VALUES
(
 TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-12-19 13:30:00, YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
 TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-12-19 14:33:00, YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
);
```

Comment: missing quotes around timestamp. these are 2 different arguments. use `TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-12-19 13:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

Comment: You are calling functions to convert strings to timestamps. You could simply use timestamp literals instead: `VALUES ( timestamp '2016-12-19 13:30:00', timestamp '2016-12-19 14:33:00' );`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to close the single quote after the date and start before the format mask:

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME
(START_TIME,
 END_TIME
)
VALUES
(
 TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-12-19 13:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
 TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-12-19 14:33:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
);
```

Comment: wow I've looked at this for 20 minutes or more. Thanks for pointing out my boneheadednesss. :)